How do you reference static files from a Maui Project that reside in the RCL project?
I have all of my code in my RCL project,(classes, models, css, images etc)
I can get all of the above except images folder by references _content in my index.html.
Pretty much all of my RCL views reference images inside the images folder
In my Blazor project Program.cs I use app.UseStaticFiles() which then I can see my images folder in my RCL.
The problem is MAUI doesnt have this or does it?
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureSyncfusionCore()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("InputLayoutIcons.ttf", "InputLayoutIcons");
                });

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView(); 
            
            builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Hybrid.Mobile.appsettings.json");

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                     .AddJsonStream(stream)
                     .Build();

            builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
            builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings").Get<MailSetting>());
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUsersService, UsersService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDapperContrib, DapperContrib>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICalendarEventsService, CalendarEventsService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(x => new BlobServiceClient(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureBlobStorageConnectionString")));
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://MYAPI.com/") });
            builder.Services.AddMudServices();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
         
            return builder.Build();

